# Multiprocessing and a global manager

Tags: python, dictionary, process, multiprocessing, future

I have

```
import concurrent.futures
from multiprocessing import Process,Manager,freeze_support
from functools import partial


def setup():
  freeze_support()
  global manager
  manager=Manager()
  global dict1
  dict1=manager.dict()
  global dict2
  dict2=manager.dict()


  load_stuff()
```

and later:

```
  def foo(file):
     #do some stuff
     foobar()

  def foobar():
      #look up some stuff in dict1,dict2

  def load_stuff():
      f=partial(foo,dict1,dict2)

      with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
           for users, tweets in executor.map(f, list_of_files):
```

But I keep getting

```
 NameError: global name 'dict1' is not defined
```

Basically: I'm spawning multiple processes, who while doing some work call a function that looks up values in two dicts. The dicts are global because I need them when I may just call foo() and foobar() without being in a new process. The processes are unable to access the dicts. How can I fix this?

Edit: I ended up making dict1 a normal global dictionary and then passing it as a variable to f, then redeclaring it as global inside f and it works. Not memory efficient, but this process only runs once and the dicts use only around 45mb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since default parameters values are bound at compile time, this should work:

```
def foobar(dict1=dict1, dict2=dict2):
    pass
```

---

Wait, so `load_stuff` needs to have been defined before `setup` and `setup` needs to have been defined before `foobar`, but it seems `foobar` and `load_stuff` are next to each other.

It's not very clear to me how your functions are laid out. Perhaps you need to have an additional declaration of `dict1` and `dict2` as module-level variables somewhere (while keeping the global statements unchanged).

---

That said, I believe that your method of accessing shared variables in your concurrent program is not idiomatic.

Comment: I ended up just passing it to f as a parameter then declaring it as a global var. I know its not memory efficient but the dict is only 45mb in memory so that is fine. This process only runs once anyway.